# ttest with correction for multiple test in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to compare two data sets 1 and 2 to show that they are similar:

Date set 1 (Vector): 1 1 2 3 1 2 1 3 4 1 Mean: 1.9
Data set 2 (Vector): 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 Mean: 1.83

I need to use *t-test* with correction for multiple testing like Bonferroni. I tried multcompare but I am not sure how I could link it to the t-test.

Can somebody show an easy example how to it?

Comment: Do you want to show that the empirical distributions or the two samples are rather similar? Or the means? Or the means of the populations the values were samples? What does "similar" mean? And what does the question have to do with multiple testing? A lot of questions ;)

Comment: I have two samples with a huge amount of measurements. The means are pretty close together, however the p-value for a test shows a significant difference. The problem is that with such a large number of measurements every t-test will be significant...this is why I need to find a way to correct this. I also already tried ranksum and kstest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a test that is based on a null hypothesis of "no difference" (like the t-test) to show that two things are similar (not different). A *null hypothesis test* can only say whether there's sufficient evidence to believe the null hypothesis is wrong, not that it is true.

It is also not correct to turn to multiple comparisons correction here, for two reasons: 1. Apparently you only want to do this because you don't like the result of the test. Changing a test procedure because of the result *falsifies it*. The circumstance that this is a common practice in some branches of science doesn't change this fact. 2. You are only doing a single comparison between two samples. There *are no* multiple comparisons to correct for in your application.

Since the t-test tells you that there is a difference between the two data sets, you can't simply assume that there is none. But the circumstance that a difference is *significant* (and therefore presumably real) does not mean that it is *relevant*. So I'd recommend you argue that you have a small, statistically significant, but irrelevant difference between the two data sets. However, "relevance" as used here is not a statistical concept, and there are no tools of *inferential statistics* that can help you with defining relevance. You need an argument based on your application, or some standard levels common to your field.

In some fields, relevance is commonly defined with respect to the *statistical size of an effect*. For the t-test, the common measure of effect size is [Cohen's d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d). It is roughly equal to the t-value multiplied by `sqrt(n1 + n2 - 2)`. Cohen (1992, "A power primer") proposes to call a d of 0.2 "small", 0.5 "medium", and 0.8 "large".